# perl pattern matching non-greedy match for string

Tags: string, perl, design-patterns, matching, greedy

I have a string which is like `ascv/zxc/zxc-asd/zx.java` now I wish to cut the string at second  `/` and get the String value as `ascv/zxc`.

Similarly I will input the special character type and its level. Based on the input it should cut the string. E.g. from first match for character `-`; or  3rd match of `/`

Any  help  is highly appreciated.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Do you care to share what you have tried, why it's not working? See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have tried :- $a="ascv/zxc/zxc-asd/zx.java", ($str1,$str2)=split(/\//,$a); output should be ascv/zxc not ascv,zxc

Comment: Several ways to do this, `split` is probably the simplest.  Just saw your comment edit: use `join` to glue them back together.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $str = 'ascv/zxc/zxc-asd/zx.java';

say truncate_at($str, '/', 1);
say truncate_at($str, '/', 2);
say truncate_at($str, '/', 3);
say truncate_at($str, '/', 4);
say truncate_at($str, '-', 1);

sub truncate_at {

  my ($str, $sep, $n) = @_;
  my @offsets;

  push @offsets, $-[0] while $str =~ m|\Q$sep|g;
  substr($str, $offsets[$n-1]) = '' if $n <= @offsets;

  $str;
}
```

**output**

```
ascv
ascv/zxc
ascv/zxc/zxc-asd
ascv/zxc/zxc-asd/zx.java
ascv/zxc/zxc
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
my $str = 'ascv/zxc/zxc-asd/zx.java';
$str =~ s#^([^/]+/[^/]+).*#$1#;
say $str;
```

**output:**

```
ascv/zxc
```

Comment: thanks but  it can vary upto what level i need to match , it can be match first special character(/) or match 4th, its given by argument.instance- cut a string before 3rd "/" match, cut a string before 5th match of "/"